# div to image via python

Tags: python, django, slack

i want to make a div image with python and send it as an attachment to slack, is there a way I can do this? i basiclly send message to slack with the following codes. Is what I want to do possible?

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-duyuru" id="inputGroup-sizing-default" style="font-weight: 500;">Duyuru Tipi:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-duyuru" name="dolusturulmatarihi" id="dolusturulmatarihi" aria-label="Default" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-duyuru" style="font-weight: 500;">Açıklama:</span>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-duyuru" name="daciklama" id="daciklama" aria-label="With textarea">XX:XX </textarea>
    </div>
```

view;

```
 from django_slack import slack_message
    
     web_hook_url = 'XXXX'
     slack_msg = {
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "test1.",
            "color": "#f5b400",
            "pretext": "test2",
            "author_name": "TEST ALARMI2",
            "author_link": "https://XX/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "test4",
            "title_link": "https://XX/",
            "text": "test5",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Techops",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
        }
    ]
}
        requests.post(web_hook_url,data=json.dumps(slack_msg))
```

Comment: as I know Chrome (and maybe Firefox) has JavaScript function to take screenshot - maybe it can even take screenshot of selected element on page. So you may try to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control Chrome and use JavaScript to run function which take screenshot.

Comment: @furas hi, Thanks for your suggestion, but I need to take a screenshot of a dynamic page. To explain, I want to save the screenshot of that div and send it as a message to slack while the user is filling out the form and saving it.

Comment: `selenium` controls web browser which can run JavaScript - so it works with dynamic page. But problem is when you want to save screen when user is using this page. Maybe it would need to use external program to take screenshot - like `pyautogui` - but this take screen shot of full page and it doesn't know where is `div` on page.